# Why the skip at the beginning of the first line doesn't apply

Tags: xetex, paragraphs

I cannot obtain a **skip/indention** at the beginning of the first line below.
Any help?

[image]

**EDIT:
Your hint doesn't work for [this template](https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses)**

[image]

Comment: Most document classes suppress the indentation in the first paragraph following a title. You can try `\usepackage{indentfirst}`, but that depends on several other factors.

Comment: @egreg Great it works. But, why down-vote ?

Comment: @user2925716 - I didn't downvote your posting, and I'm also baffled why somebody would see fit to cast a downvote. Actually, I just *upvoted* your posting, to "even the score".

Comment: @Mico Traditionally typesetitng the first paragraph after a title (or figure or table or..) does not start with an indentation. To me the question boiled down to typesetting.I think that this site covers both LaTeX code as to your to get the appearance you are after

Comment: Do you want indentation for *all* paragraphs afer sectioning titles or only this particular one?

Comment: @user691586 Perhaps *all*. Can I get help on this site on how to **minimize** the work needed to convert this  [template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook) into my own thesis ?

Comment: Then if for `all` the `indentfirst` approach already advised may be a good shot.

Comment: @PeterWilson - To me, a downvote on this site is a very strong signal of condemnation and rejection. Not the best way to start a conversation...

Comment: @user2925716 I didn't downvote. On the other hand, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Mico Erm, sorry, I was the downvoter but it was a slip. I must've touched the arrow without realizing (on smartphone) and I noticed only now. It wasn't meant.

Comment: @egreg Or even you may have a look at my **EDIT** please ?

Comment: @user2925716 -- The EDIT points to a page which lists four templates, one based on memoir, and the other three unattributed (I didn't examine the templates themselves).  To which template does the "doesn't work" apply, or to all four?

Comment: @barbarabeeton To this: `kaobook`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have noticed only now that there are in fact four templates. Which one is the most `noble` ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please see also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686424/thesis-template-doesnt-work-with-xetex) question.

Comment: The class passes `parskip=half` to `scrbook`. Add `parskip=off` to the class options.

Comment: @user2925716 -- I'm sorry; I'm not familiar with any of these thesis templates, or with thesis templates in general.  I was looking to see if there was anything obvious, but aside from the ambiguity caused by four possibilities, there wasn't.  I'm often not able to fully answer a question, but try to make sure there's enough information for someone more familiar with the area to answer easily.

Comment: @egreg Works. Do you happen to know why `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}` doesn't work for the classic thesis template ? It should yield a decorative style of chapter headings.

Comment: @user2925716 Why would you use `fncychap` at all? My personal opinion is that the package provides very ugly chapter styles. Anyway, you're using a template that works hard to define a specific chapter style: why using the template if you want to change it?

Answer (score 2):

The `kaobook` class passes `parskip=half` to the `scrbook` class it's based on. Add

```
parskip=off
```

to the class options and

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\hspace{20pt}` might work (the default indent is 20pt).